# Cross-domain authentication - user identification

Tags: php, authentication, cross-domain

I am trying my hand at cross domain authentication... I have looked into ways of passing data between domains. I am thinking about using a beacon img (1x1 transparent image) to pass tokens.

What I have been stumped with is: How do I identify who the user is?

To Clarify:

I want to authenticate all users with a central domain (domain1.com)

when a user is logged in to domain1.com and then visits domain2.com, it will send a request with a request token to domain1.com to check if this users is logged in. But how does domain1.com know which of the currently logged in users is this?

I have read about a trans parent image and similar thing, but i have been having trouble finding any resources/material to learn more about these methods.

If someone can explain this to me I would really appreciate it.

BTW. I am using PHP for the server side and am ok with using jQuery or JS on client side.

Comment: @Dave Chen - Yes I have, but I am currently using my own login system, and it works fairly well, and I don't see any security problems. I was hoping to integrate into that system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to do it but store an api key on both domains(same key), and when user goes from domain1.com to domain2.com send a variable of the api key and a userid that exists on both domains. Check to see if the api key is valid and if so make sure the user is existent. Also when a user logs in store that in the database and delete it when the user logs out.

Comment: I'll give it a try... or at least some form of it.